# XSLT to HTML transformation. generate-id() error in Qt5

Tags: c++, linux, xslt, qt5, xslt-2.0

I do a XSLT to HTML transformation using the method recommended in Qt doc:

```
QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);
query.setFocus(QUrl("myInput.xml"));
query.setQuery(QUrl("myStylesheet.xsl"));
query.evaluateTo(out);
```

Inside XSLT I use `generate-id()` method to generate unique ids for different DIV blocks. It works perfectly in Qt4.8, but not in Qt5.4
¿Anyone knows a reason for that, and how to solve this?

Edit: I get no error. What I get in Qt5 is always the same ID, while in Qt4 I get a different, unique ID each time i call `generate-id()`.

I generate the ID this way:

```
<xsl:variable name="tc_id" select="generate-id()"/>
```

And I use it this way:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$tc_id"/>
```

This is the cpp code doing the transformation:

```
    // generate output string
    QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);
    QString output;
    query.setFocus(QUrl(_final_output_filepath.c_str()));
    query.setQuery(xslt_code.c_str());
    query.evaluateTo(&output);
```

Edit 2:

When I use this code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
 xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes">

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each select="trial/testsuite">

   <xsl:for-each select="testcase">
      <xsl:variable name="tc_index" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="tc_id" select="generate-id(.)"/>

       <xsl:value-of select="$tc_id"/>
   </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...I get always the same ID.

Comment: Can you update with the error you are receiving? And with a (minimal, please!) working example that shows input XML and XSLT and expected output XML (which currently doesn't work), see [mcve], so that we can repro your problem and actively suggest solutions.

Comment: PS, shouldn't the last line be `query.evaluateTo(&out)`?

Comment: Sorry, I can not make public the code. I add some snippets.

Comment: That's why I linked to [mcve]. If you can show a repeatable example (not necessarily your current code), we can repeat it and help you.

Comment: I see your update, but can you elaborate? What is the context node? Can you create a full, minimal XSLT that shows how this fails?

Comment: Sorry. It is not easy to isolate such an example. Complex Qt5 program, with complex XSL file, and a large XML input file. I am talking about hundreds of lines in XSL and thousands in XML. I'll try to get something, but it is not straightforward. The main question is: why in Qt4 the method works perfectly, and why the same program, in Qt5, the method returns always the same id?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your issue, but if this problem is repeatable, all you need is two lines of XML and three lines of XSLT with the `generate-id()` function. And your Qt C++ code shown already is four lines. If it cannot be reproduced trivially that way, the issue may be in your (larger) code.

Comment: To answer your "main question", I still need to see how you use it. The XSLT 2.0 impl. is experimental. If you used `generate-id()` originally wrongly, but Qt gave you an ID anyway, it may have done so incorrectly. It is also possible that you hit the inline problem. I can go on and on. Bottom line, I need to see _how you use it in XSLT 2.0 and with what context node to replicate the issue_.

Comment: There it is a full example. Thanks @Abel for your time.

Comment: I also realized that when I call `current()` inside a `xsl:for-each`, it returns an empty string

Comment: If `current()` returns an empty string, perhaps the node does not have content. You should test if `current()` actually returns a node (i.e., with `xsl:copy-of`) and compare it with using `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:template match="/">
>    <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/> --
>    <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/> --
>    <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
> ```

Thanks for the snippet. This was indeed why I kept bugging you about giving a reproducible example.

What happens here is that you call the `generate-id()` function multiple times without changing the context node. The default argument for this function is the context node (here: `/`, or the root node).

Unless you change the context node, this function is deliberately designed to be stable. That means that, if called repeatedly with the same argument (also meaning: the same default argument, the same context), it **must** return the same string.

It is also designed such that it always returns a unique string per distinct node. Two nodes are distinct if they have different position in the document (i.e., they are distinct even if they look the same, but appear on multiple places).

Bottom line: you didn't hit a bug in the Qt implementation of XSLT 2.0, but you hit a resolved issue that was a bug and was incidentally used as a feature.

---

If you require a unique ID in XSLT 2.0, and you are bound to giving the same context, there is probably something else that changes: for instance, you can be in a loop going over a set of numbers or strings. You can use this info to create a unique string.

Another "hack" in XSLT 2.0 is to use a single point in the specification where determinism is not guaranteed: on creation of new nodes:

```
<xsl:function name="my:gen-id" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:sequence select="generate-id(my:gen-id-getnode())" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="my:gen-id-getnode" as="element()">
    <node />
</xsl:function>
```

This small function touches on some advanced concepts and recently, people discussing in the XSL Working Group, have agreed that optimizing away the creation of the new node is allowed if the node identity is not required. Whether or not a processor correctly detects this is unclear.

In XSLT 3.0 a new property has been introduced on `xsl:function`: `@new-each-time`, which informs the processor that the function should be evaluated each time and not get inlined.

---

### Update: tests with Qt 5.5 or 5.4

I have tested a variant of your code with Qt because I couldn't believe that identity (which is a core concept of XSLT) doesn't work with it. So, I created a document with similar-looking nodes of all six types (I ignored namespace nodes, as support for it is optional).

#### Input test document

```
<root test="bla">
    <?pi do-something ?>
    <row></row>
    <!-- comment here -->
    <row>content</row>
    <row>content</row>
    <row id="bla" xml:id="bla">content</row>
</root>
```

#### XSLT 2.0 code

Code slightly adjusted due to Qt not supporting `@separator` correctly.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:my="my-functions"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="string-join(
            ('gen-id(', 
            my:decorate(.), '[', my:depth(.), ']', ') = ', generate-id(.), 
            '&#xA;'), '')"  />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- remove prev. and use this if you think for-each is different -->
    <!--xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//node() | //@*">
            <xsl:value-of select="string-join(
                ('gen-id(', 
                my:decorate(.), '[', my:depth(.), ']', ') = ', generate-id(.), 
                '&#xA;'), '')"  />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template-->

    <xsl:function name="my:depth" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="node" />
        <xsl:sequence select="
            string(count($node/(/)//node()[$node >> .]) + 1)" />
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="my:decorate">
        <xsl:param name="node" />
        <xsl:sequence select="
            ($node/self::text(), 'text')[2],
            ($node/self::element(), concat('Q{}', name($node)))[2],
            ($node/self::document-node(), 'document')[2],
            ($node/self::comment(), 'comment')[2],
            ($node/self::attribute(), concat('@', name($node)))[2],
            ($node/self::processing-instruction(), 'processing-instruction')[2]
            " />
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output using [Exselt](http://exselt.net)

```
gen-id(Q{}root[1]) = x1e2
gen-id(@test[2]) = x1e2a0
gen-id(processing-instruction[2]) = x1p3
gen-id(Q{}row[3]) = x1e4
gen-id(comment[4]) = x1c5
gen-id(Q{}row[5]) = x1e6
gen-id(text[6]) = x1t7
gen-id(Q{}row[7]) = x1e8
gen-id(text[8]) = x1t9
gen-id(Q{}row[9]) = x1e10
gen-id(@id[10]) = x1e10a0
gen-id(@xml:id[10]) = x1e10a1
gen-id(text[10]) = x1t11
```

#### Output using Qt 5.5 or 5.4

I used the pre-build `xmlpatterns.exe` and called it as `xmlpatterns test.xsl input.xml`, but its code uses the same libraries you are using:

```
gen-id(Q{}root[1]) = T756525610
gen-id(@test[2]) = T756525620
gen-id(text[2]) = T756525630
gen-id(processing-instruction[3]) = T756525640
gen-id(text[4]) = T756525650
gen-id(Q{}row[5]) = T756525660
gen-id(text[6]) = T756525670
gen-id(comment[7]) = T756525680
gen-id(text[8]) = T756525690
gen-id(Q{}row[9]) = T7565256100
gen-id(text[10]) = T7565256110
gen-id(text[11]) = T7565256120
gen-id(Q{}row[12]) = T7565256130
gen-id(text[13]) = T7565256140
gen-id(text[14]) = T7565256150
gen-id(Q{}row[15]) = T7565256160
gen-id(@id[16]) = T7565256170
gen-id(@xml:id[16]) = T7565256180
gen-id(text[16]) = T7565256190
gen-id(text[17]) = T7565256200
```

As this shows, stripping space does not work with Qt, as it considers them text nodes. But as you can also see, the `generate-id` function works for each and every node, whether they are processing instructions, text nodes, look the same, are empty elements etc. It didn't matter whether:

- Using `generate-id()` vs `generate-id(.)`
- Putting it in `xsl:for-each` or normal template processing
- Using a variable to store the result prior to using
- Hiding `generate-id()` inside another function

All returned the same, valid result.

---

### UPDATE: Workaround

There's a relative expensive, yet workable workaround that you may be able to use, assuming that the generated ID in itself must be unique per document and node, but is not used in another way then for uniqueness (for instance, if used for cross-references, this will work).

```
<xsl:variable name="doc" select=".//node()" />

<xsl:function name="my:gen-id" as="xs:integer">
    <xsl:param name="elem" as="node()" />
    <xsl:sequence select="
        for $i in 1 to count($doc)
        return if($doc[$i] is $elem then $i else ())" />
</xsl:function>
```

This obviously has a performance hit, but if your documents are not that big and/or you do not call this function too often, it should be ok. You may consider creating a key if the subset for which you need this is defined.

Comment: Sorry, I just changed the code because I realized that, in the example I gave you, I was calling the method within the same node. Actually, I call the `generate-id` method in a foreach loop as I added right now. Sorry for that.

Comment: @pedromateo, thanks for the update. I had meanwhile written the rest of my response. You can try the proposed workaround and see if Qt behaves differently, but as I see your code, you indeed hit a bug in Qt's updated version of XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @pedromateo, I have updated my answer to include a workaround if you are stuck with this functionality.

Comment: many thanks for your help. However, I am getting this error: `No namespace binding exists for the prefix my in my:gen-id`. Sure it is because I forgot to write something obvious about the namespace, but I do not know what. I call the function this way: `<xsl:variable name="tc_id" select="my:gen-id()"/>`

Comment: @pedromateo, as with any user-defined stylesheet function, you must declare a namespace for it. See also my update above, I still think you are doing _something_ wrong with your code, as however I try, it is impossible to replicate. You can try my code above to see if your results are the same.

Comment: @pedromateo, as with any user-defined stylesheet function, you must declare a namespace for it. See my update above, I still think you are doing something wrong with your code, as however I try, it is impossible to replicate. You can try my code above to see if your results are the same. Also, _please try your code and mine with the commandline version of `xmlpatterns.exe`_, it may reveal whether the issue is with XSLT or with your C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

A call to `generate-id()` returns a generated id of the context node and of course, if the context does not change, you will always get the same value.

Comment: I changed the example code, which was wrong for the same reason you are commenting in your answer. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution for this problem. It seems to be some differences between Qt4 and Qt5 XSLT transformation engine in Linux.

The following code worked fine in Qt4, but not in Qt5. `tc_id` has always the same value:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="testcase">
     <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@result != 'pass'">

         <xsl:variable name="tc_id" select="generate-id(.)"/>

         <xsl:attribute name="onClick">
            ExpandCollapse('<xsl:value-of select="$tc_id"/>');
         </xsl:attribute>

         <div style="display:none">
            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$tc_id"/></xsl:attribute>
         </div>

      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         ...
      </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

And the following code works fine both in Qt4 and Qt5:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="testcase">
     <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@result != 'pass'">

         <xsl:attribute name="onClick">
            ExpandCollapse('<xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/>');
         </xsl:attribute>

         <div style="display:none">
            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/></xsl:attribute>
         </div>

      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         ...
      </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

It seems there is some problem with declaring the variable.